# Which record of the answer for calculating the integral is more correct?

Tags: integration

I need to calculate:
$\int_3^9 - \frac{\ln x}{x}dx $
I found:
$$\int \frac{\ln x}{x}dx = -\frac{1}{2}  \ln^2⁡{|x|}+C,$$ and next:

$$\int_3^9 - \frac{\ln x}{x}dx = -\frac{1}{2}  \ln^2⁡{|9|}-(-\frac{1}{2}  \ln^2⁡{|3|} )=-\frac{1}{2}  \ln^2{⁡9}+\frac{1}{2} \ln^2⁡{3}.$$

But, $-\frac{1}{2}  \ln^2{⁡9}+\frac{1}{2} \ln^2⁡{3}$ can be written as: $\frac{1}{2} (\ln^2{⁡3}-\ln^2⁡{9} )$.

[Wolfram offers another answer](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20-lnx%2Fx%2C%20x%3D3..9%20%20%3D%201%2F2%20%28%28ln%281%2F3%29%29%28ln27%29%29): $\frac{1}{2} (\ln{\frac{1}{3}} \cdot \ln{27})$

Which answer according to the rules of mathematics is better written as final?

Comment: Looks like I have to explain my position. And so, I believe that 1/2*ln(27)*ln(1/3) is the best option, since it does not contain a degree, and allows you to calculate the answer in just three steps. In complexity, this is the same as the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO I think this question is opinion based and will probably be closed soon, but I wanted to give my view as an Introduction to calculus teacher.

First, if I ask my students:

> Evaluate the following integral$$\int_3^9-\frac{\ln x}{x}dx$$

Then I'll accept your answer of
$$\frac12(\ln^23-\ln^29)\tag{1}$$
I would even have accepted your previous answer where the $\frac12$ was distributed.

Now, how do we get from your answer to WolframAlpha answer. By noting we have a square difference, and factor it.
$$\frac12(\ln^23-\ln^29)=\frac12(\ln3-\ln9)(\ln3+\ln9)$$
Using logarithm's laws to simplify
$$\frac12(\ln3-\ln9)(\ln3+\ln9)=\frac12\left(\ln\frac39\ln3\cdot9\right)$$
$$\frac12\left(\ln\frac13\cdot\ln27\right)\tag{2}$$

Not every student will be able to get from $(1)$ to $(2)$. If I want students to get to the WolframAlpha answer, I would have asked the question differently. Something like

> Show that$$\int_3^9-\frac{\ln x}{x}dx =\frac12\left(\ln\frac13\cdot\ln27\right)$$

To answer your question directly, it depends on what I want to see from my students. If I want to evaluate their abilities to integrate, your answer is fine. If I want to evaluate their ability to recognize square difference, then I want the WolfeamAlpha answer.

Comment: I believe that in mathematics, there are certain rules for writing answers that should be sought, for example, when writing polynomials, the correct form has the form when the degree of the denominator > the degree of the numerator. I want to find out what kind of response is more appropriate for this case. I personally believe that the best answer is the one where there are fewer operations, that is, 1/2*ln(27)*ln(1/3) it is better, since there are already squaring x.

Answer (score 0):

Both answer are equivalent:

$\frac{1}{2}(\ln^23-\ln^29)=\frac{1}{2}(\ln^23-\ln^23^2)=\frac12(\ln^23-4\ln^23)=\frac12(-3\ln3\cdot\ln3)=\frac12\ln27\ln\frac13$

I rules I used:

$\ln(x^y)=y\ln(x)$

$-\ln(x)=\ln(\frac{1}{x})$

In my opinion, the first one is aesthetic, but both are acceptable.

Comment: Why not 1/2*ln(27)*ln(1/3) ?

Comment: Is it less aesthetic?

Comment: Both are acceptable. Opinions on which answers are more aesthetic vary per person, so mathematics teachers have to be flexible on which answers to accept. There is no objective way to say which one is "better written".